# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,3' to data type int in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query when i try to delete comma separated values it throw a error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,3' to data type int.".Pls help me to overcome this issue.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDeleteCustomerGroupLocationMap]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @i_LocationID int,
    @i_CustomerGroupID varchar

    --WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomerGroupLocationMap WHERE LocationID = @i_LocationID AND CustomerGroupID = @i_CustomerGroupID)
    BEGIN

        DELETE CustomerGroupLocationMap WHERE  LocationID = @i_LocationID AND CustomerGroupID = (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable( @i_CustomerGroupID));

    END
END
```

Comment: But seeing as '1,3' is not an int - what value are you looking for and why?

Comment: The size of @i_CustomerGroupID is not specified so it uses the default of 1 character. You probably want it to be something else.

Comment: what is the result of CSVToTable looks like ?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Makes a good point that '1,3' will get truncated to 1 but then it is difficult to see how you can get the error in the title at all except if you are passing the string as parameter 1.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen S. Hansen i want to pass comma separated value to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most probably the error is comming from here. Try changing it to

```
DELETE CustomerGroupLocationMap 
WHERE  LocationID = @i_LocationID 
AND    CustomerGroupID IN 
       (
           SELECT [column name] 
           FROM   dbo.CSVToTable( @i_CustomerGroupID)
       );
```

replace "[column name]" with the actual column name from CSVToTable

Comment: Hey Ur code works .But if i delete one value remaining all values get deleted.

Comment: post the value for SELECT [column name] 
           FROM   dbo.CSVToTable( @i_CustomerGroupID)

Comment: @Anand When i try to delete one value all the values are getting deleted.

Comment: the CSVToTable() function may be returning wrong results.Check inside the function and its output.

Comment: You have the CustomerGroupID in the target table.I dont know why you use a function in delete while you directly check in IF EXISTS statement for that column